# Why are the water tank walls made of stretch film warping a lot whereas theoretically they shouldn't that much?

Tags: pressure, stresses, strength, water-pressure

I am building a water tank of custom dimensions (1.5 m x 0.72 m x 0.86 m) out of stretch film. The stretch film is wrapped around a steel frame (see here for more info on this [open source project](https://ca-ressemble-a-du-fake.github.io/recuperateur_d_eau_en_film_etirable/)).

I measured the force to bend a piece of stretch film : I stuck the film above the hole of a glass (standing on a kitchen scale) and pressed on it with a another smaller glass (of contact area Sc [disc of diameter 7 cm). When the film started to warp I wrote down the value on the scale (M = 1.5 kg) and stopped the experiment.

So I computed the maximum pressure that the film could hold without warping too much with Pmax = (M x g) / Sc = (1.5 x 10 ) / (3.14 * (7 x 10^-2)^2 / 2) : I found about 4 kPa.

The water tank is 1.5 m tall so Pwater = rho x g x H ~ 1000 x 10 x 1.5 = 15 kPa.

Consequently at the bottom of the walls, 4 layers of 22 µm thick stretch film would be sufficient to hold the stored water. But I applied a safety coefficient of 2 and rounded it to 10 layers. These should be strong enough.

But with already 350 - 400 L in the water tank the walls starts warping. Why is it so whereas I took a safety margin and the tank is only half full ?

[image: Warped side walls of my water tank]

Is it because I did not tighten enough the stretch film around the frame (you can see that the frame bars are bent because of the tightened film) ? Or is it because I made a wrong assumption in my calculation ?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Simple, you are making the wall of a flexible and stretchable material.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I changed the title to reflect more accurately what stroke me. @DKNguyen I understand the weight will be different but the pressure will be the same at a depth of 1.5m under water. Maybe it is because as soon as the side walls warp, the water pressure becomes non uniform in direction (it's not orthogonal to the frame side anymore) and the film has to carry even more load and warps more and more. If I could tighten it very strongly with enough tightened layers it could carry more water. But so far 400 L is perfect. By the way DKNguyen which formula would you use ?

Comment: @DKNguyen gravity **is** assumed as 10 by many engineers - especially when dealing with water and water flow since the losses are so much bigger than the difference between 9.81, or 9.807 depending on location, and 10.

Comment: Thank you that's a good suggestion. I'll have a look at case studies on water pressure on the wall in a water tower. I'll have now many things to learn and understand before I finish my guide !

Comment: I went and looked it up a bit more and it seems your equation is correct. The lateral pressure on the wall is only dependent on the height of the water column and not the total mass of the water being contained. Seems so strange to me. I guess the water away from the walls really does just sit on top of itself? That means that a 5m tall wall holding back the sea from flooding into a canal only has to be the same strength has a 5m tall wall holding back a swimming pool.

Comment: @DKNguyen but walls for the sea are thicker and designed differently - due to the energy provided by waves...

Comment: @SolarMike True but still. It's difficult to wrap my mind around that you're holding back way more water for the same pressure,

Answer (score 0):

#### Your experiment to determine how strong the film is was flawed.

Hang film out horizontally about 2 feet and put some water in it, you'll see it immediately deforms.  Your hole-and-glass experiment seriously overestimated the strength of the film.  Or re-calc the film strength based on your now more obvious results.

Comment: So my hole-and-glass experiment is not a good mock-up of the reality! What I could do is stretch the film between 2 parallel (horizontal bars) spaced 80 cm apart from each other (the length of the frame), put a scale on its center and press on it. Then I will know the force that a single layer can cope without deforming too much and I could extrapolate on how many layers I should put. It wouldn't be flawed this time, would it ?

Answer (score 0):

Fluid pressure tends to bend straight walls. If you want to keep them straight, they have to have high [second moment of area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area) which is problem for thin stretch. Deformed stretch has a curvature so it can withstand the fluid pressure with membrane stresses (it can be modelled using [membrane theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_theory_of_shells)), so the stretch has to have good tensile stiffness, which it has.

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DvWDCmbPxs&ab_channel=ConnorHolland), where even steel plates nicely bend under pressure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this video, I didn't know about water (or even grease) forming that can make a perfect sphere!

Comment: @CaraDuf I was once told that if you build rectangular pressure vessel, nature will try to turn it into spherical or cylindrical during pressure test :).

Answer (score 0):

Your test with two glasses, if I understand it, was testing the load and pressure that the film could support at a small area.
The problem is that as the area increases, the amount of stretch does not stay the same.
As you increase the area of the film

- The force is proportional to the AREA of the film. Double the dimensions and you get 4 times the area and 4 times the load.
- But the length of film supporting the load is proportional to the LENGTH of the outside border of the area. Double the dimensions and you only have 2 times the amount of film to support 4 times the load.
- The angle of deflection at the centre of the film is proportional to the stretch and then this is integrated from the centre of the film to the outside. So you have another factor that is proportional to the dimensions.
  -Then the total distance of the deflection is equal to the angle of deflection, integrated along the distance again.

To view a 2 dimensional version of this, which is probably much easier to understand, look at formula for deflection of a Simply Supported Beam, Uniform Distributed Load.  https://mechanicalc.com/reference/beam-deflection-tables

In the 2 dimensional case the final deflection is proportional to the length of the beam, to the power of 4. Your case is obviously more complicated, but you can see that scaling up from a small test to a large water tank will give a lot more deflection than one would first assume.

Comment: This is very interesting although I did not understand how you get your second bullet point `But the length of film supporting the load is proportional to the LENGTH of the outside border of the area`. Nevertheless for the studied case we have a ratio Lreal / Lmockup ~ 10. So the deflection will be 10^4 larger in reality than on the mockup. That is if the deflection was 1 mm on the mockup it should be 10 m in the reality. But that doesn't hold. What did I misunderstand ?

Comment: The reason you don't get deflection of 10^4 times as much is:     This is not  the same as the case of the beam I linked to above: the load in your film is much more supported by tension in the film, not bending stiffness of the film.  Film has nearly zero bending stiffness, so the geometry very quickly distorts until the film is in tension.  In the bending of the beam case being examined, they are assuming small deflections, which is not your case.

Comment: Your film has to support the tension that is created by the pressure. Look at one vertical edge of your cube, the film has a given cross-section that is supporting this tension. The cross-section is equal to the thickness of the film multiplied by the length of the vertical edge. ie. the height of the cube.  For a given film thickness (modelling your multiple layers of plastic as one membrane for convenience), the cross-section supporting this load is equal to the thickness x length.  But load is proportional to area x pressure.  =  length x length x pressure.

Comment: Thank you very much @PatMc this helped me understand the situation !